# Form validation function for React

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, react.js

I need to validate multiple input fields using React. I am using a simple if-else block for each input field but I would like to optimize my code and make it better. I feel there can be a better way to validate multiple input fields.

```
  validateForm = () => {
    const {
      firstName, lastName, mobileNo, city, empType, salary
    } = this.state;

    if (firstName !== '') {
      this.setState({
        firstNameMsg: '',
        validFirstName: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        firstNameMsg: 'Please enter a vaild first name.',
        validFirstName: true
      });
    }
    if (lastName !== '') {
      this.setState({
        lastNameMsg: '',
        validLastName: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        lastNameMsg: 'Please enter a vaild last name.',
        validLastName: true
      });
    }

    if (mobileNo.match(/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/) && !(mobileNo.match(/0{5,}/))) {
      this.setState({
        mobileNoMsg: '',
        validMobileNo: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        mobileNoMsg: 'Please enter a vaild mobile number.',
        validMobileNo: true
      });
    }

    if (city !== '') {
      this.setState({
        cityMsg: '',
        validCity: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        cityMsg: 'Please enter a vaild city.',
        validCity: true
      });
    }

    if (empType !== 'Self-Employed') {
      this.setState({
        empTypeMsg: '',
        validEmpType: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        empTypeMsg: 'Some msg',
        validEmpType: true
      });
    }

    if (salary !== '') {
      this.setState({
        salaryMsg: '',
        validSalary: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        salaryMsg: 'Please enter a vaild salary.',
        validSalary: true
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: For completeness, can you include the code for `setState()` as well?

Comment: @200_success `setState()`  [is native to react](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Honestly, I would look at using a framework like Yup for doing form validation.

Answer (score 1):

Validation is so common that I recommend generalizing it a little bit (not too much though, there are too many special cases).

One way is to create validations, schema, and data separate from each other. For example:

```js
const validators = {
    required: (config, value) => value !== '',
    mobileNo: (config, value) => value.match(/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/) && !(value.match(/0{5,}/)),
    equal: (config, value) => value === config.value
}

const validate = (data, schema) => {
    const messages = {}

    for(let [name, rules] of Object.entries(schema)){
        for(let rule of rules){
            if(!validators[rule.type](rule, data[name])){
                if(!messages.hasOwnProperty(name)) messages[name] = []
                messages[name].push(rule.msg)
            }
        }
    }

    return messages
}

const schema = {
    firstName: [{type: 'required', msg: 'Please enter a valid first name.'}],
    lastName: [{type: 'required', msg: 'Please enter a valid last name.'}],
    mobileNo: [{type: 'required', msg: 'Please enter a mobile number'}, {type: 'mobileNo', msg: 'Please enter a valid mobile number.'}],
    city: [{type: 'required', msg: 'Please enter a vaild city.'}],
    empType: [{type: 'equal', value: 'Self-Employed', msg: 'Some msg'}],
    salary: [{type: 'required', msg: 'Please enter a vaild salary.'}],
}

// In react component
validateForm(){
    const validationMessages = validate(this.state.data, schema)
    this.setState({validationMessages})
}
```

You can take this much further by adding templated validation messages, and fancy rules of all sorts. But I recommend keeping it simple. You can make multiple variants of the validate function for different needs as they come.